# SQL: How to get a string located between two specific characters in a given string

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, substring

I'm sending a file location to my stored procedure.

There might be two scenarios:

```
1. \\filedirectory\Department\Project\2000-01-12\
2. \\filedirectory\Departments\Project\20000112\
```

I'm trying to find a way to get a string between 2 last slashes and convert it into the MMDDYY format.

How do I do that?

Comment: I'm using MS Server 2012

Comment: Feels like this could be done in code and sent as a separate parameter.

Comment: I'm not writing a code for this. I'm just executing a stored procedure that has a parameter, a folder name as specified in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have gotten carried away but this works.

```
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(MAX) = '\\filedirectory\Department\Project\2000-01-12\'

SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10),CAST(REPLACE(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@path), 1, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@path), 2))), '\', '') AS DATE), 1), '/', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way...

```
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(MAX) = '\\filedirectory\Department\Project\2000-01-12\'

select 
    replace(convert(varchar,cast(replace(right(@path,charindex('\',reverse(@path),2)-1),'\','') as date),1),'/','')
```